# Writing a header in iPython Notebook causes the header to be invisible

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In **iPython Notebook** running Python 2.x, when we write a markdown `#header` in a new cell and execute it, nothing appears

[image]

Every word I've tried seem to work for the header except `header`. How can we have a header with the word `header`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Markdown is a documentation language, and Python is a programming language; these have different uses.

Comment: @jpaugh I think in iPython notebook's, having `#` at the beginning of the markdown causes that line to be a header

Comment: Okay. Maybe I'm missing the boat completely here. I didn't know iPython accepted Markdown syntax. But, I'm guessing that it is getting confused on whether it's Python or Markdown (much as I did!)

Answer (score 3):

I get the same issue.  Here is a workaround.

```
<h1> header
```

Comment: Confirmed. This is a bug. I have submitted a [ticket](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/100).

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem in jupyter. Saving the notebook does not make the '#' markup symbol go away and leaves the text in a garish blue color, as you illustrate with the image you shared.

The only way I can get the header to assume its proper appearance is to close the notebook and reopen it. Then the text appears as it should.